# Was Kusha born from grass?

Tags: reference-request, birth, kusha, lava

कुश कुश अस्, means grass, and Bard AI says:

> There is a folktale that says that Kusha was born from grass. According to the story, Kusha's twin brother, Lava, was playing in the forest when he wandered off and was lost. Valmiki, the sage who was raising the boys, was worried and searched for Lava everywhere. When he could not find him, Valmiki used his divine powers to create a second son from a piece of kusha grass. He named the boy Kusha, and raised him alongside Lava.

Is this story in any scripture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original story in the Ramayana is this:

> During the night that Shatrughna passed in the leaf-thatched hut, Sita gave birth to two children and, at midnight, the youthful ascetics brought the pleasant and auspicious tidings to Valmiki, saying:—
>
> “O Blessed One, Rama’s consort has given birth to twin sons, do you perform the rites that will preserve them from evil forces.”
>
> Hearing these words, the great Rishi went to see those newly-born Ones, who were as effulgent as the new moon and full of vigour, like unto twin offspring of the Gods.
>
> Coming to w'here Sita was, on beholding those tw’o infants, his heart was filled with delight and he performed the Rakshasa Rite.1 Taking a handful of Kusha Grass with its roots, that Twice-born One, Valmiki, pronounced the formula of protection for the destruction of evil forces, saying:—
>
> “Since they will rub the first born of the children with the Kusha Grass blessed by the aid of Mantras, his name shall be Kusha and, as the last born will be carefully dried by the female ascetics with the roots of the grass, he shall be called Lava. Therefore those two shall be called Kusha and Lava and, by these names that I have given them, they will become renowned.”
> [[7.66]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424840.html)

The alternative story comes from the [Katha Sarita Sagara](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/40588/pg40588-images.html#v1pb487):

> The hermits, pleased with that conduct of [Sita], gave her a blessing which enabled her to give birth to a son, and she, while dwelling there, in good time did give birth to a son, and the hermit Válmíki gave him the name of Lava. One day she took the child and went to bathe, and the hermit, seeing that it was not in the hut, thought— “She is in the habit, when she goes to bathe, of leaving her child behind her, so what has become of the child? Surely it has been carried off by a wild beast. I will create another, otherwise Sítá, on returning from bathing, will die of grief.” **Under this impression, the hermit made a pure babe of kuśa grass, resembling Lava**, and placed him there, and Sítá came, and seeing it, said to the hermit, “I have my own boy, so whence came this one, hermit?” When the hermit Válmíki heard this, he told her exactly what had taken place, and said, “Blameless one, receive this second son named Kuśa, because I by my power created him out of kuśa grass.” When he said this to her, Sítá brought up those two sons Kuśa and Lava, for whom Válmíki performed the sacraments. And those two young princes of the Kshatriya race, even when children, learned the use of all heavenly weapons, and all sciences from the hermit Válmíki.